# Pressing any key on excel just moving up cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, keyboard

I am using Microsoft Excel for Mac (version: 16.59) via Office 365 subscription from my work.

Recently, excel started behaving weird where pressing any key on my keyboard will move up one cell, instead of the usual function.

It is only happening for Excel and other applications are working fine. And it is happening for both my macbook pro keyboard and also for Logitech external keyboard.

Comment: You could uninstall Office and reinstall.

Comment: I know there is an advance option to change the direction of the selection when pressing `Enter`. But not pressing any key. If reinstalling doesn't work, then a long shot is to check if macros are running, perhaps there is a personal.xlsm that is causing this behavior.

Comment: In my prior life, I would mess with a friend's emulators when he wasn't looking and change all keystrokes to something else. I wouldn't know how to accomplish this in excel, but like gns mentioned, maybe there's a macro doing this. `Disable all macros`  should be a troubleshooting step.

Comment: When you say "press any type", do you mean like pressing, say, "Q"?  That causes the selection to move up one cell?  I'd say to check if there are any Keyboard "shortcuts" defined (System Prefs -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> App Shortcuts), but I just checked and those require a "modifier" key to be pressed too, like Command or Control.  Excel behaves "funny" if Scroll Lock is pressed on a PC, but I don't think we have that on Macs (and this causes the screen to scroll, not the selection to move).  But, unplug the external keyboard anyway, reboot, and try again?

Comment: I just restarted my machine and it fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Rebooting is a panacea.